# Extracting an element from XML using Entity - C#

Tags: xml, entity

I have a xml:

```
<messageheaders startindex="0" count="3" totalcount="3" xmlns="http://api.esendex.com/ns/">
- <messageheader id="74dfea3e-a196-4ae0-9595-105c9f59cc01" uri="https://api.esendex.com/v1.0/messageheaders/74dfea3e-a196-4ae0-9595-105c9f59cc01">
  <reference>EX0196276</reference> 
  <status>Submitted</status> 
  <sentat>2016-03-03T08:01:32.97Z</sentat> 
  <laststatusat>2016-03-03T08:01:32.97Z</laststatusat> 
  <submittedat>2016-03-03T08:01:32.97Z</submittedat> 
  <receivedat>2016-03-03T08:01:32.97Z</receivedat> 
  <type>SMS</type> 
- <to>
  <phonenumber>34627176544</phonenumber> 
  </to>
- <from>
  <phonenumber>447908583018</phonenumber> 
  </from>
  <summary>837680710A4714672983100303090100640000000000000...</summary> 
  <body id="74dfea3e-a196-4ae0-9595-105c9f59cc01" uri="https://api.esendex.com/v1.0/messageheaders/74dfea3e-a196-4ae0-9595-105c9f59cc01/body" /> 
  <direction>Inbound</direction> 
  <parts>1</parts> 
  <readat>0001-01-01T00:00:00Z</readat> 
  </messageheader>
- <messageheader id="8e835eda-d6d7-46e4-ab44-4df20bd133a4" uri="https://api.esendex.com/v1.0/messageheaders/8e835eda-d6d7-46e4-ab44-4df20bd133a4">
  <reference>EX0196276</reference> 
  <status>Submitted</status> 
  <sentat>2016-03-03T07:00:30.957Z</sentat> 
  <laststatusat>2016-03-03T07:00:30.957Z</laststatusat> 
  <submittedat>2016-03-03T07:00:30.957Z</submittedat> 
  <receivedat>2016-03-03T07:00:30.957Z</receivedat> 
  <type>SMS</type> 
- <to>
  <phonenumber>34627176544</phonenumber> 
  </to>
- <from>
  <phonenumber>447944489977</phonenumber> 
  </from>
  <summary>B3EB80710A470F42A782100303080000640000000000000...</summary> 
  <body id="8e835eda-d6d7-46e4-ab44-4df20bd133a4" uri="https://api.esendex.com/v1.0/messageheaders/8e835eda-d6d7-46e4-ab44-4df20bd133a4/body" /> 
  <direction>Inbound</direction> 
  <parts>1</parts> 
  <readat>2016-03-03T07:08:19.963Z</readat> 
  <readby>andrej.dolar@iskra.eu</readby> 
  </messageheader>
- <messageheader id="f9fd0867-7659-4042-a1d6-edd8699b19b3" uri="https://api.esendex.com/v1.0/messageheaders/f9fd0867-7659-4042-a1d6-edd8699b19b3">
  <reference>EX0196276</reference> 
  <status>Submitted</status> 
  <sentat>2016-03-03T06:01:33.007Z</sentat> 
  <laststatusat>2016-03-03T06:01:33.007Z</laststatusat> 
  <submittedat>2016-03-03T06:01:33.007Z</submittedat> 
  <receivedat>2016-03-03T06:01:33.007Z</receivedat> 
  <type>SMS</type> 
- <to>
  <phonenumber>34627176544</phonenumber> 
  </to>
- <from>
  <phonenumber>447944489977</phonenumber> 
  </from>
  <summary>B3EA80710A470F42A780100303070100640000000000000...</summary> 
  <body id="f9fd0867-7659-4042-a1d6-edd8699b19b3" uri="https://api.esendex.com/v1.0/messageheaders/f9fd0867-7659-4042-a1d6-edd8699b19b3/body" /> 
  <direction>Inbound</direction> 
  <parts>1</parts> 
  <readat>2016-03-03T07:08:05.497Z</readat> 
  <readby>andrej.dolar@iskra.eu</readby> 
  </messageheader>
  </messageheaders>
```

How can I get the summary value from each messageheader in messageheaders?
I tried many solutions found here but it doesnt work.

```
XElement xml = XElement.Parse(response);

var result = xml
.Elements()
.Select(s => new
{
Summary = s.Element("summary").Value.ToString()
}).ToList();
```

This code returns:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in X4SmsReceiver.dll

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: its because messageheaders has namespace attribute. Try this reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939509/xdocument-and-linq-returns-null-if-the-element-has-xmlns-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XNamespace xns = "http://api.esendex.com/ns/";
        var data = xdoc.Element(xns + "messageheaders").Elements(xns+"messageheader").Select(x => new { Summary = x.Element(xns+"summary")}).ToList();
```

Try this it works

Comment: No Problem. I think you also got to know the reason for the error. Its because of the namespace attribute. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use XSD.exe to design a class of xml tags and then by deserializing you can get the data.